# Add tab bar viewcontroller and DDMenuController in the appdelegate class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I want to add both the DDMenuController and the tab bar viewcontroller for the app.
I'm not able to add both, so plese help me solve this issue.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;
    HomeViewController *mainViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
    navigationController.delegate = self;
    DDMenuController *rootController = [[DDMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationController];
    _menuController = rootController;

    MenuListViewController *menuController = [[MenuListViewController alloc]init];
    rootController.rightViewController = menuController;


    TabbarViewController *tabBarVC  = [[TabbarViewController alloc] init];
    tabBarVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootController, nil];

    if ([tabBarVC respondsToSelector:@selector(willAppearIn:)])
    {
        [tabBarVC performSelector:@selector(willAppearIn:) withObject:navigationController];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Do you want to add first toolbar and than after add DDMenuController in one tab?

Comment: @YashpalJavia i want both should be present for the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.

first create tab bar than add DDMenuController and finally add to root view of window

This might work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;
    HomeViewController *mainViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
    navigationController.delegate = self;


    TabbarViewController *tabBarVC  = [[TabbarViewController alloc] init];
    tabBarVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootController, nil];

    if ([tabBarVC respondsToSelector:@selector(willAppearIn:)])
    {
        [tabBarVC performSelector:@selector(willAppearIn:) withObject:navigationController];
    }



    DDMenuController *rootController = [[DDMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarVC];
    _menuController = rootController;

    MenuListViewController *menuController = [[MenuListViewController alloc]init];
    rootController.rightViewController = menuController;



    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT :**

This is sequence of view controllers.

navigationViewController -> rootViewController -> main ViewController (which is default for you)

tabbar -> rootViewController -> navigationViewController (if you want many than you can put many view in tabbarViewController)

manuViewController (which is show in right side by DDMenuController)

DDMenuController -> rootViewController -> tabbar

and

DDMenuController -> rightController -> manuViewController

Window -> rootviewcontroller -> DDMenuController